# Estimating the upper bound for $\prod\limits_{p \le x}{p^{\frac{1}{p}}}$

Tags: prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds, primorial, chebyshev-function

An upper bound for the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) can be found based on the first [chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function).

From $\vartheta(x) < 1.00028x$, it is clear that:

$$\prod\limits_{p \le x}p \le e^{1.00028x} < (2.72)^x$$

I am looking at the following and am having trouble figuring out the upper bound.

$$\prod\limits_{p \le x}p^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

Is there a function similiar to the first chebyshev function that can be used?  The second chebyshev function is not helpful since:

$$\psi(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\vartheta(x^{\frac{1}{n}}})$$

I am wondering if there is an upper bound better than a very simple approach such as this:

$$\prod\limits_{p \le x}p^{\frac{1}{p}} < \prod\limits_{p \le x}p^{\frac{1}{2}} < \sqrt{(2.72)^x} <  (1.65)^x$$

Comment: I'm not too familiar with number theory. Could you do $e^{\sum_{p\leq x} \log(p)/p}$ and use Chebyshev's result that $\sum_{p\leq x} \log(p)/p = \log(x) + O(1)$? Probably there are modifications of Chebyshev's result that give strict bounds on $\sum_{p\leq x} \log(p)/p$.

Comment: By the way, running some numerical experiments on the product is a good way to see that its grows looks much more linear than exponential—that can help steer us towards stronger/more effective estimation techniques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like pretty much all products, the way to approach this product is to take logarithms and first estimate
$$
\log \prod_{p\le x} p^{1/p} = \sum_{p\le x} \frac{\log p}p.
$$
It turns out that this sum is precisely [one treated by Mertens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems): in 1874 he proved that
$$
\biggl| \sum_{p\le x} \frac{\log p}p - \log x \biggr| \le 2,
$$
which already shows that
$\displaystyle e^{-2}x \le \prod_{p\le x} p^{1/p} \le e^2x$.

It turns out that the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) is equivalent to the assertion
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \biggl( \sum_{p\le x} \frac{\log p}p - (\log x + A) \biggr) = 0,
$$
where $A$ is a constant related to [Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant) $\gamma$, namely
$$
A = -\gamma - \sum_p \frac{\log p}{p(p-1)} \approx -1.33258.
$$
We conclude that
$\displaystyle\prod_{p\le x} p^{1/p} \sim e^Ax$
where $e^A \approx 0.263795$.